# Does my RPi uses video RAM for tunneling X over ssh?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, memory

I use my Pi in headless mode, and I like to use X over SSH occasionally to run graphics only apps like the Pi store, and a few of my programs. I'd like to increase my RAM by decreasing GPU RAM, in accordance to the answer of this question.

For example, this is how I would start the session: `ssh -X pi@[IP ADDRESS]`. I can then run `startxfce4` and it'll start the GUI in X11 on my Mac, resulting in a VNC-style connection.

In doing so, I'm running the X server on my Mac, so does that mean that no video RAM is being used on the RPi because my Mac is the one handling the Graphics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it should.

You run the [X-server](http://foldoc.org/X+Window+System) on your Mac. And the Pi only runs X-clients, that talk X-protocol tunnelled through SSH with the server on your Mac, which does all the drawing.

Since you won't be using a lot of GPU RAM, you can set the split with `raspi-config`, to a smaller value. That way you have a bit more RAM available for your programs to use.

Answer (score 3):

The very minimum you can allocate to the GPU is 16MB. To do so edit the file `/boot/config.txt`:

Setting:

```
gpu_mem=16
```

(edit: a reboot is required for this change to take effect). This is required to load the GPU firmware, not just the framebuffer. See http://elinux.org/RPiconfig for more info.

If you want to reduce memory use consider using dropbear rather than OpenSSH (saves ~10MB), dash over bash (~1MB), remove unsed ttys (~3MB), you can go further:

[Raspberry Pi Raspbian tuning / optimising / optimizing for reduced memory usage ( dropbear + getty + no ipv6 + dash + swap + noop + overclock + syslogd )](https://extremeshok.com/2012/07/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-tuning-optimising-optimizing-for-reduced-memory-usage/)